# Does the Postgres HSTORE() function only operate on text/integer datatypes in 9.5?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

When I use the PostgreSQL 9.5 `hstore()` construction function on a `row` object in a query, it seems to only return columns in that row that are the `text` or `integer` datatypes.  I can see that my `timestamp` and `character varying` columns are by default omitted from the HSTORE object that comes back.

In PostgreSQL 9.3 constructing a `hstore` object would include `timestamp` and `character varying` columns of the row as well, how can I get this behavior back?

Specifically my table's DDL looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sessions
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sessions_id_seq'::regclass),
  session_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  data text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT sessions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Below is the output of running a `hstore` constructor; note that the `session_id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` columns (keys) do not get added to the hstore even when their values are not null:

```
select hstore(sessions.*) from sessions limit 1;

hstore                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------
"id"=>"15435216", "data"=>"DjfBv="
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. *All* columns should be included. Even with NULL values. (I just tested to verify.)

Maybe you are inadvertently using a different table with the same name in a different schema?
Aside: you can simplify to (equivalent):

```
SELECT hstore(sessions) FROM public.sessions LIMIT 1;
```

I schema-qualified `public.sessions` to make sure the right table is used.
I assume you are aware of the role of the schema search path?

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Hmm qualifying the schema with `public.sessions` didn't do fix it, good thought though.  I'm relatively positive it's the only `sessions` table in that database let alone schema. Perhaps is an issue with the operating system/distribution of postgres I am using.  I confirmed it is working perfectly on my Ubuntu installation of 9.3 (with `postgresql-contrib-9.3` installed from apt-get to for the hstore module), whereas the problematic one was installed via the MSI installer on Windows 10  and is version of 9.5.3.

Comment: @nomizzz: Well, there has to be *some* explanation, but I don't see how that would make the difference. I tested 9.5.3 on Windows 7 and it works as expected.

Comment: Agreed -- now that I know that's the expected behavior on 9.5 as well it's most likely some configuration setting or scoping setting different in the defaults that I'm missing.  I'll report back when I figure it out.